# How to echo from read function + extra text

Tags: linux, bash

I have an another issue with this script:

#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter desired time: " desiredtime

echo "$desiredtime"

I want the echo to have the desiredtime that the user entered and 00 after it

echo "$desiredtime + 00"

so if user entered 1400 the echo should be 140000

I tried :
echo "($desiredtime)00"

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: `echo "${desiredtime}00"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo "${desiredline}00"`

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and therein the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".